# Cannot stop md raid6 array

Tags: mdadm, iscsi, lvm2, raid6

I setup a raid6 array on top of iscsi and lvm shared logical volumes that I use to make sure only one node part of iscsi network can use the raid volume at a time.

Today I fail to stop the volume. Here is (short) full trace of what I can see happens:

```
[root@ceph03 ~]# mdadm --stop /dev/md/disk12
mdadm: failed to stop array /dev/md/disk12: Success
[root@ceph03 ~]#
```

Please ignore the ceph reference in the prompt above; there is nothing ceph-related in the setup.

I can see no clue in `/var/log/messages` or from `dmesg` when I run the command as above, although `dmesg` shows this trace:

```
[86802.298276] md/raid:md127: device dm-10 operational as raid disk 3
[86802.298309] md/raid:md127: device dm-9 operational as raid disk 2
[86802.298333] md/raid:md127: device dm-8 operational as raid disk 1
[86802.298358] md/raid:md127: device dm-7 operational as raid disk 0
[86802.298858] md/raid:md127: raid level 6 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[86802.311605] md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 15625334784
[86802.466827] block device autoloading is deprecated and will be removed.
[86802.628293] md/raid:md126: device dm-14 operational as raid disk 3
[86802.628330] md/raid:md126: device dm-13 operational as raid disk 2
[86802.628355] md/raid:md126: device dm-12 operational as raid disk 1
[86802.628379] md/raid:md126: device dm-11 operational as raid disk 0
[86802.628884] md/raid:md126: raid level 6 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[86802.639225] md126: detected capacity change from 0 to 15625334784
[86802.843550] block device autoloading is deprecated and will be removed.
[86802.961863] md/raid:md125: device dm-18 operational as raid disk 3
[86802.961906] md/raid:md125: device dm-17 operational as raid disk 2
[86802.961932] md/raid:md125: device dm-16 operational as raid disk 1
[86802.962722] md/raid:md125: device dm-15 operational as raid disk 0
[86802.963869] md/raid:md125: raid level 6 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[86803.009078] md125: detected capacity change from 0 to 15625334784
[538389.817257] systemd-rc-local-generator[9716]: /etc/rc.d/rc.local is not marked executable, skipping.
[541853.695869] block device autoloading is deprecated and will be removed.
[542584.298089] md: md124 stopped.
[542799.943574] block device autoloading is deprecated and will be removed.
[543000.305701] md/raid:md124: device dm-22 operational as raid disk 2
[543000.306453] md/raid:md124: device dm-21 operational as raid disk 3
[543000.307064] md/raid:md124: device dm-20 operational as raid disk 0
[543000.307658] md/raid:md124: device dm-19 operational as raid disk 1
[543000.308793] md/raid:md124: raid level 6 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[543000.329321] md124: detected capacity change from 0 to 15625334784
```

But there is no additional output when I try to stop the array.

For context with the command and trace above:

```
[root@ceph03 ~]# ls -l /dev/md*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 9, 124 Apr 11 19:05 /dev/md124
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 9, 125 Apr 11 16:45 /dev/md125
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 9, 126 Apr 11 16:45 /dev/md126
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 9, 127 Apr 11 16:45 /dev/md127

/dev/md:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Apr 11 19:05 disk12 -> ../md124
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Apr 11 16:45 disk7 -> ../md127
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Apr 11 16:45 disk8 -> ../md126
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Apr 11 16:45 disk9 -> ../md125
[root@ceph03 ~]#
```

and the device is not used for anything else as far as I can see:

```
[root@ceph03 ~]# lsblk /dev/md124
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
md124   9:124  0  7.3T  0 raid6 
[root@ceph03 ~]#
```

All nodes part of the network run Rocky Linux 9.1.
Where else can I look for what is preventing me to stop the array?

Comment: The situation described in the question sustained for about 16 hours. About 30 minutes after posting the question, `mdadm --stop /dev/md/disk12` did manage to stop the raid6 array.

Comment: ... and it happens again. The same raid6 volume on top of iscsi but on another node part of the network.

Comment: It turns out I had several concurrent execution of a script, some trying to assemble the raid device and its member volumes, some other trying to stop them. Everything worked better when all script execution instances were killed. If anyone know away some logs could have let me know that the raid device was being work on by another process and what was its command, then I would be keen to know.